# New dynamic Angular components are always placed at the top of the container

Tags: angular, angular-dynamic-components

I am creating dynamic components in the following way

```
<div #newComponents></div>

addCategory = (categoryName: string) => {
const formRowFactory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(FormRowComponent);
const { instance: formRowComponent } = this.newComponents.createComponent(
  formRowFactory, // playing with the index over here
);
}
```

No matter what I use for the index in the createComponent call I always get the new component to be placed as first. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Don't pass an index value. The default behavior is to append new components to the view.

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz demo, because it should put new component using provided index or as the last one if you didn't specify index parameter.

Comment: @cgTag thanks that solved my problem